# Adding Docstring easily in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, docstring

I'm used to write in Pycharm when if you type `"""` in the beginning of a function you'll get automatically generated docstring that you just need to complete, for example-

```py
def foo(x, y):
    """
    :param x:
    :param y:
    """
    return x + y
```

Is there any equivalent shortcut for quick Docstring generation for Google Colab?